# Подмена цвета PNG при наведении мыши

Tags: html, css, hover, png

Подскажите, как с помощью CSS, при наведении курсора, заменить цвет PNG-иконки (например, такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] ) с серого на красный.

Comment: сделать ещё одну иконку красного цвета и менять её при наведении

Comment: Если png, то цвет background можно менять по :hover

Answer (score 7):

В CSS3 это возможно с помощью свойства `filter`:

```css
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: sepia(1) hue-rotate(320deg) saturate(10);
  filter: sepia(1) hue-rotate(320deg) saturate(10);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbcA9.png">
```

Цепочка фильтров такова (порядок важен!):

- `sepia` - по сути, делает изображение монохромным с рыжим оттенком;
- `hue-rotate` - вращение цветового круга до нужного оттенка;
- `saturate` - насыщенность цвета.

[Источник](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)

---

Чтобы какой-либо цвет превратить в белый:

```css
body { background: #ccc; }

img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100) brightness(200);
  filter: grayscale(100) brightness(200);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjpgK.png">
```

Здесь цепочка следующая:

- `grayscale` - обесцвечиваем изображение;
- `brightness` - устанавливаем яркость с заведомо завышенным значением.

Comment: я дико извиняюсь, а как из красного, при наведении, сделать белый цвет картинки

Comment: @MikhaelBalkizov: дополнил.

Answer (score 2):

Подготовьте отдельный спрайт с иконками разных цветов (как показано ниже). В CSS-стилях зафиксируйте размеры блока. Задайте для блока фоновое изображение. У псевдокласса :hover пропишите смещение этого изображения равное высоте (или ширине) картинки. В результате получится элемент, который чуть-чуть изменяется при наведении указателя мыши.

[image: спрайт с вертикально расположенными иконками]

```css
.i-folder {
  height: 42px;
  width: 57px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjpgK.png);
}
.i-folder:hover {
  background-position: 0px 42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="i-folder"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Поддержка браузерами: [caniuse.com/#search=mask](https://caniuse.com/#search=mask)

```css
div {
    -webkit-mask-size: contain;
    -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask-position: center;
    -webkit-mask-image: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1086/1086563.svg');
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000;
}

div:nth-child(1) { background: linear-gradient(#e74c3c, #f1c40f); }
div:nth-child(2) { background-color: #1842de; }
div:nth-child(3) { background-color: #ffff00; }
div:nth-child(4) { background-color: #3498db; }
div:nth-child(5) { background-color: #9b59b6; }
div:nth-child(6) { background-color: #2ecc71; }
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```